# Is there a data structure with 2 indizes / a key-key data-structure?

Tags: java, dictionary, data-structures, key, bimap

Is there a data structure in Java (java util, guava...) that allows me to store "key value" pairs that can also be interpreted as value-key?

Example:

```
Datastructure d = new Datastructure();

d.add(1, "foo");
d.add(21 "bar");
d.add(33 "hello");
d.add(55 "world");
```

A function like `d.get1(1)` should return `foo`.
A function like `d.get2("foo")` should return `1`.

A function like `d.get1(33)` should return `hello`.
A function like `d.get2("hello")` should return `33`.

...

Is there something that works like this?

Comment: Key can be unique but values cannot be, then in this case how will you get Key by value ? There is no such in Java as of now.

Comment: from what you have written you just need a Map (e.g. HashMap)

Comment: Hey @Adam, how will you get key by get(value) in java.I know there is map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is essentially implemented by Guava's `BiMap`.
You can use [guava](https://github.com/google/guava)'s BiMap like this -

```
BiMap<Integer, String> biMap = HashBiMap.create();
biMap.put(1, "foo");
biMap.put(21, "bar");

System.out.println(biMap.get("1"))); //foo
System.out.println(biMap.inverse().get("bar"))); //21
```

**Link:**
- [Guide to guava BiMap](https://www.baeldung.com/guava-bimap)
- [BiMap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) java doc

**Alternatively,** you can use apache common [`BiDiMap`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/BidiMap.html) like this:

```
BidiMap<String, String> map = new DualHashBidiMap<>();
map.put(1, "foo");
map.put(21, "bar");
System.out.println(map.get(1)); //1

//reversing the mapping 
BidiMap<String, String> reversedMap = map.inverseBidiMap();
System.out.println(reversedMap.get("foo")); //1
```

Answer (score 2):

In the Apache commons collections library is the [BidiMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/BidiMap.html) interface and some implementations thereof. The interface has a method to get the inverse map, i.e. a map where role of key and value are swapped.

If you don't want to use this class you could easily implement your own class using two maps internally.

Answer (score 1):

There is not such a class in Java, but you can do what you want with this:

```
Map<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

map.put(1, "foo");
map.put(21, "bar");
map.put(33, "hello");
map.put(55, "world");
map.put("foo", 1);
map.put("bar", 21);
map.put("hello", 33);
map.put("world", 55);

System.out.println(map.get(1)); // foo
System.out.println(map.get("foo")); // 1
```

Looks and is weird, but works as you want.

Or you can create your own class that works as you need, maybe using one map as I showed, or two maps like: `Map<Integer, String> map1... Map<String, Integer> map2...`

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks. That would work for my simple example. But a problem could occur if it's a Map<Integer, Integer> for example with the entries (3,1) and (2,3) for example. No problem with map.put(1,3), but map.put(3,2) would overwrite the (3,1) entry.

Comment: Use 2 different maps in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Guava has the [`BiMap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) interface, with a variety of implementations, including `HashBiMap` and `ImmutableBiMap`, which provide an `inverse()` view to do a reverse lookup.  Note also that they are implemented more efficiently than simply storing a pair of maps, one in each direction -- though at some level, it's impossible to build a *significantly* better implementation.